# Accessing external images behind basic authentication in Cordova

Tags: android, image, cordova, ionic-framework, basic-authentication

I have an IP camera and I need to access images from it with my Cordova app. I know the URL to the image but it's behind HTTP basic authentication. How can I tell my app the credentials to access the image? Having the credentials in the img src (http://username:password@198.168.x.x...) does not work.

I have tried XMLHttpRequest to get the image binary data with it and convert that further, but it does not feel like a good solution. Is it possible to tell cordova auth credentials and apply them automatically when trying to access images?